# Unable to scrape "shopee.com.my" top selling products page

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, scrapy, python-requests

I am trying to scrape "shopee.com.my" top selling products with scrape and also tried with requests but failed in getting valid JSON object. my requests code is given below:

```
import requests as r
import json

data = {
'authority': 'shopee.com.my',
'method': 'GET',
'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
'scheme': 'https',
'accept': '*/*, application/json',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
'x-api-source': 'pc',
'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
'x-shopee-language': 'en',
'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
}

subcat_url = '/Boys-Fashion-cat.27.2427'
id = subcat_url.split('.')[-1]
data['path'] = f'/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id={id}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'
data['referer'] = f'https://shopee.com.my{subcat_url}?page=0&sortBy=sales'
url = f'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&match_id={id}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'

req = r.get(url, headers=data)
items = req.json()['items']
print(items)
print(f'Items length: {len(items)}')
```

here is my scrapy code:

```
import scrapy
import json
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.http.cookies import CookieJar

header_data = {'authority': 'shopee.com.my',
    'method': 'GET',
    'scheme': 'https',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
    # 'cookie': 'SPC_U=-; SPC_IA=-1; SPC_EC=-; SPC_F=7jrWAm4XYNNtyVAk83GPknN8NbCMQEIk; REC_T_ID=476673f8-eeb0-11ea-8919-48df374df85c; _gcl_au=1.1.1197882328.1599225148; _med=refer; _fbp=fb.2.1599225150134.114138691; language=en; _ga=GA1.3.1167355736.1599225151; csrftoken=mu9M72KLd73P9QJusB9zFBP6wV3NGg85; _gid=GA1.3.273342972.1603211749; SPC_SI=yxvc89nmqe97ldvpo6wgeybtc8berzyd; welcomePkgShown=true; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; REC_MD_41_1000027=1603289427_0_50_0_48; SPC_CT_48918e31="1603289273.lUS7x9IuKN5vNbhzibZCOHrIf6vVQmykU/TXxiOii7w="; SPC_CT_57540430="1603289278.FLT3IdzHC32RmEzFxkOi9pI7qhKIs/yq328elYMuwps="; SPC_CT_50ee4e78="1603289299.gvjW32HwgiQGN/4kj2Ac3YFrpqyHVTO8+UjM+uzxy4E="; _dc_gtm_UA-61915055-6=1; SPC_CT_75d7a2b7="1603289557.t5FvxXhnJacZrKkjnIWCUbAgAxAQ3hG5c1tZBzafwc4="; SPC_R_T_ID="n6Ek85JJY1JZATlhgutfB4KB3qrbmFDYX1+udv1EBAPegPE9xuzM8HFeCy1duskY9+DVLJxe4RqaabhyUuojHQG0NI2TqegihbAge+s3k7w="; SPC_T_IV="SGNXqyZ1jtRYpo5kFeKtYg=="; SPC_R_T_IV="SGNXqyZ1jtRYpo5kFeKtYg=="; SPC_T_ID="n6Ek85JJY1JZATlhgutfB4KB3qrbmFDYX1+udv1EBAPegPE9xuzM8HFeCy1duskY9+DVLJxe4RqaabhyUuojHQG0NI2TqegihbAge+s3k7w="',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'x-api-source': 'pc',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'x-shopee-language': 'en',
    }


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    allowed_domains = ['shopee.com', 'shopee.com.my', 'shopee.com.my/api/']


    def start_requests(self):
        subcat_url = '/Baby-Toddler-Play-cat.27.23785'
        id = subcat_url.split('.')[-1]
        header_data['path'] = f'/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id={id}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'
        header_data['referer'] = f'https://shopee.com.my{subcat_url}?page=0&sortBy=sales'
        url = f'https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id={id}&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2'

       


        yield Request(url=url, headers=header_data)

    def parse_data(self, response):
        try:
            jdata = json.loads(response.body)
            return None
        except Exception as e:
            print(f'exception: {e}')
            print(response.body)
            return None

        items = jdata['items']

        for item in items:
            name = item['name']
            image_path = item['image']
            absolute_image = f'https://cf.shopee.com.my/file/{image_path}_tn'
            print(f'this is  absolute image {absolute_image}')
            monthly_sold = 'pending'
            price = float(item['price'])/100000
            total_sold = item['sold']
            location = item['shop_location']
            stock = item['stock']

            print(name)
            print(price)
            print(total_sold)
            print(location)
            print(stock)
```

not using cookies now but also tried with fresh cookies but no response.
Here are some example links where some so them responses always valid JSON object but some links not return any response. see below api and direct browser links:

https://shopee.com.my/Kids-Sports-Outdoor-Play-cat.27.21700?page=0&sortBy=sales
https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=21700&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2

https://shopee.com.my/Bath-Toiletries-cat.27.2422
https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/?by=sales&limit=50&match_id=2422&newest=0&order=desc&page_type=search&version=2

you can also see API links in network tab:
[network tab link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFixj.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing a required header I send them like this and it worked

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests

    headers = {
        'authority': 'shopee.com.my',
        'pragma': 'no-cache',
        'cache-control': 'no-cache',
        'x-shopee-language': 'en',
        'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
        'if-none-match-': '55b03-c3d70d78b473147beeb6551fa9df8ca0',
        'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36',
        'x-api-source': 'pc',
        'accept': '*/*',
        'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
        'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
        'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
        'referer': 'https://shopee.com.my/Kids-Sports-Outdoor-Play-cat.27.21700?page=0&sortBy=sales',
        'accept-language': 'es-US,es;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,es-419;q=0.6',
        # 'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.1866522785.1603486253; _fbp=fb.2.1603486253254.1114160447; SPC_IA=-1; SPC_EC=-; SPC_U=-; SPC_F=9RO26eJM7IQiFlxki0dAdQCcCsgPwz67; REC_T_ID=71a698d6-1571-11eb-9baf-48df3757c438; SPC_SI=mall.n58BgakbNjCD5RDYlsQJ8EurmBkH5HIY; SPC_CT_c49f0fdc="1603486254.GqWz1BPlfz3MKmUufL3eTwFqgUfdKWcWVf2xiJI7nSk="; SPC_R_T_ID="89vber/2TKnfACAmGbXpxC3BzHc0ajEQMPxgMbAlZnQlgEo7YWmya0sf/KRt1FsoZvaFYKoNDk+Rh9YWLWsNMH324iqgZePbam1q9QpYQlE="; SPC_T_IV="vko6vAtWsyHuqteFHAoPIA=="; SPC_R_T_IV="vko6vAtWsyHuqteFHAoPIA=="; SPC_T_ID="89vber/2TKnfACAmGbXpxC3BzHc0ajEQMPxgMbAlZnQlgEo7YWmya0sf/KRt1FsoZvaFYKoNDk+Rh9YWLWsNMH324iqgZePbam1q9QpYQlE="; AMP_TOKEN=%24NOT_FOUND; _ga=GA1.3.602723004.1603486255; _gid=GA1.3.657631736.1603486255; _dc_gtm_UA-61915055-6=1; language=en',
    }

    params = (
        ('by', 'sales'),
        ('limit', '50'),
        ('match_id', '21700'),
        ('newest', '0'),
        ('order', 'desc'),
        ('page_type', 'search'),
        ('version', '2'),
    )

    response = requests.get('https://shopee.com.my/api/v2/search_items/', headers=headers, params=params)
    pprint(response.json())
```

Comment: Dear sir,
            You have added "if-none-match" header that's why it is giving valid response but i have 124 API links and we have to add that header manually so i can't add them manually.  

   Also these headers will be changed when cookies expires and that "if-none-match" header will be no more. I think that's not a solution. but thanks for your time and support.

Comment: It is not the complete solution, but now that you know the header is needed, you just need to figure out how to fill it automatically. See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/dynamic-content.html